# How to multiplex 8 pieces of 74141 without transistors?

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, nixie

I'd like to use 8 pieces of 74141 in order to drive the same amount of Nixies with an Arduino. What approaches will I need to consider?

Update: I'm able to drive 1 single Nixie with a 74141. The problem here is that there are not enough pins on Arduino to drive more so I'll need a solution for this.

Comment: You mention "mulitplex" in your title. Multiplexing might not be needed for what you want to achieve. Explain why you think multiplexing is needed. I think you don't need multiplexing, I think you need counters and/or shift registers but feel free to show how multiplexing is better. Have you searched for circuits that are used for controlling nixie tubes? What do you get when searching for "Nixie display circuit" in Google and then press the **Images** tab. I can already see a circuit that uses 74141 and 7490 / 7492 (these are counter ICs) to drive the 74141s.

Comment: https://www.dos4ever.com/nixie1/nixie1.html

Comment: You ask "what IC will I need" and that makes this a **shopping question** which are Off-topic. So be clever and ask: "How can I control 74141 with Nixie tubes?" Since then you're asking for **design / circuit suggestions** (which is OK) instead of asking for some product to do a function. But still, there are plenty of circuit examples to be found so go search for them.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for mentioning 7490 / 7492 as well as the term "counter IC".  I'll do some more research on this. What I thought initially is to drive the 74141 ICs similarly to a single LED in a matrix - the only difference is to have 4 "channels" instead of 1 "channel".

Comment: As the chip is not stateful you need to back up and consider the whole problem.   If you can time-slice, one possibility is that you don't really demultiplex the decoders, but rather use something else to select the other electrode of one display at a time (eg how it would be done with LEDs).  The other possibility is that you demultiplex the inputs using something like shift registers, or I2C I/O expander, etc letting you drive the display with 100% rather than shared duty cycle.  Likely what you really should do is start with some *research* to discover how others have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that you don't multiplex the 74141 parts, you drive them directly from a dedicated driver. You need to store the 4-bit value in some type of memory device, such as a latch, flip-flop, shift register, or more complicated IC. There are a lot of ways to attack the problem, depending on what you're most comfortable with.

- Use a 4-bit latch or flip-flop (7475, 7477) to store one digit at a time. Use 8x 4-bit latches, with each clock/enable pin brought out separately.
- Use a 4+ bit shift register with parallel outputs (74164) with each chip chained to the next one. Uses only 2-3 Arduino pins, but you must update all digits simultaneously.
- Use an I/O expander (MCP23017) and an I2C interface on the Arduino. This allows you to address each digit individually while only needing two pins on the Arduino.

Comment: Wow great and clear answer! Couldn't resist writing this "thanks" kind of comment.